# Classify column in positive, negative and neutral in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe like to one below and would like to add a column indicating wether the value in the second column is either neutral (0), positive, or negative (so, the third column should be: negative, neutral, positive).

Thank you in advanced.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c('one', 'two', 'three'), y = c(-0.237, 0, 0.345))
```

Comment: What did you try? This is a very basic operation in R

Answer (score 1):

Can use nested `ifelse()`

```
df$s <- ifelse(sign(df$y) == -1, "negative",
        ifelse(sign(df$y) == 0, "neutral", "positive"))
```

The `ifelse()` function takes a logical argument - e.g. is the result of `sign()` -1? and returns the second argument if that is true and third if it is false. With nested ifelse statements, the third argument is then another `ifelse()`.

---

Note that you could also use simpler logical operations rather than `sign()`, e.g.

```
df$s <- ifelse(df$y<0, "negative",
        ifelse(df$y>0, "positive", 
        "neutral"))
```

Comment: I see, was not familiar with the fact that you can nest ifelse. Thank you

Comment: Why not just use `df$y < 0`, `df$y == 0`, and `df$y > 0` in `ifelse()`? The use of `sign()` is redundant.

Comment: True, it's just an artefact of my first approach being `df$s <- sign(df$y)` - I switched from that because the OP specifically wanted the text labels

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
df$z <- factor(sign(df$y), (-1):1, c('negative', 'neutral', 'positive'))
df
      x      y        z
1   one -0,237 negative
2   two  0,000  neutral
3 three  0,345 positive
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df$z <- sapply(df$y, function(a){
    if(a < 0){"negative"
    } else if(a > 0){"positive"
    } else{"neutral"}})
```

output:

```
> df
      x      y        z
1   one -0.237 negative
2   two  0.000  neutral
3 three  0.345 positive
```